# Using wait_for with timeouts with list of tasks

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

So, I have a list of tasks which I want to schedule concurrently in a non-blocking fashion.
Basically, `gather` should do the trick. 
Like

```
tasks = [ asyncio.create_task(some_task()) in bleh]
results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

But then, I also need a timeout. What I want is that any task which takes > timeout time cancels and I proceed with what I have.

I fould `asyncio.wait` primitive. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives

But then the doc says:
`Run awaitable objects in the aws set concurrently and block until the condition specified by return_when.`

Which seems to suggest that it blocks...

It seems that asyncio.wait_for will do the trick 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouts
But how do i send in the list of awaitables rather than just an awaitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is that any task which takes > timeout time cancels and I proceed with what I have.

This is straightforward to achieve with `asyncio.wait()`:

```
# Wait for tasks to finish, but no more than a second.
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=1)
# Cancel the ones not done by now.
for fut in pending:
    fut.cancel()
# Results are available as x.result() on futures in `done`
```

> Which seems to suggest that [asyncio.wait] blocks...

It only blocks the current coroutine, the same as `gather` or `wait_for`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know when to use `asyncio.as_completed` . It seems very similar to `asyncio.wait`

Comment: @Fraz `as_completed` is for when you're interested in the results of the tasks as they arrive. `wait` will wait for all to finish (by default) or for the first one (if given `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`). I generally find `wait()` to be more useful in practice, especially as its return value gives you information which tasks have finished and which have not, which the code in the answer puts to good use.